# Find the segmento $NO$ in semicircle below

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

In the graph, calculate: $NO$, if the golden section of $SO$ measures $8u$.($T$ point of tangency).(Answer$4u$)

[image]

Could someone explain what this golden section would be and how to use it in this exercise

Comment: It means "golden section" / "golden mean" / "golden ratio" : $(1+\sqrt{5})/2$ , though the Question is not very clear.

Comment: How much would "SO" be worth with this information?

Comment: The Question is not very clear , there are multiple Interpretations giving multiple Answers. Where was this Question given ? Might be translation Issue. What is the Dotted line ? Is that Dotted line going though Circle Centre ? Too many vague Points here.

Comment: It is a Peruvian issue. There is no translation error. The design is very clear. The dotted line is the radius.

Comment: HINT. The solution is correct if $SO={1+\sqrt5\over2}\cdot 8u$.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Could you post the solution? I couldn't develop it

Comment: [1] Assumption is that Dotted line is radius , though might be valid , due to arrow ! [2] "if the golden section of SO measures 8u ...." : What is u ? [3] Nice answer by user dfnu assumes "u=ϕ ...." , though the Question wording is not saying that. [4] Better worded Question might be "if SO measures 8ϕ (where ϕ is the golden section) ...." [5] Answer given by user dfnu is 4 & textbook answer is 4u=4ϕ : which is Correct ? [6] There are other unclear Issues in the Question !

Comment: @Prem The answer given by dfnu is correct, taking into account the position $u=1$, which shouldn't be surprising.

Comment: I am not sure , I think user dfnu is taking OS=8ϕ , whereas Question indicates that OS=8u , which is weird. That is either Contradiction or ϕ=u=1 , @Intelligentipauca , Hence Question seems wrong !!

Comment: @Prem The question states $OS=8\phi u$: "the **golden section** of  measures 8".

Comment: How can $SO$ be $(1+\sqrt{5})/2 \approx 1.6$, when $u$ equals $1$ and the distance from $S$ to the top of the semi-circle being $\sqrt{2} \approx 1.4$? $SO$ should be smaller than that.

Comment: @Dominique How do you know that the distance from  to the top of the semicircle is $\sqrt2$?

Comment: @Intelligentipauca: Pythagoras, using $u$ (the radius) being $1$ :-)

Comment: The radius IS NOT equal to $u$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Dividing $SO$ into two parts by a point $B$ we will have the golden section of $SO = 8u$
$\dfrac{SO}{8}=\dfrac{8}{BO} \implies \dfrac{SO}{8}=\dfrac{8}{SO-8}\implies SO^2-8SO-64 =0\\
\therefore SO=4(1+\sqrt5)=8\underbrace{\dfrac{(1+\sqrt5)}{2}}_{\varphi} \implies \color{red}{SO = 8\varphi}$

$NS = L \\
\triangle CNS: L^2=r^2+h^2(I)\\
\triangle CTN: h^2=TN^2+r^2(II)\\
\triangle BTN : r^2=TN^2+(L-r)^2(III)\\
(I)+(II): TN^2 = L^2-2r^2(IV)\\
(IV)em(III): {r^2}= L^2-2r^2+L^2-2Lr+{r^2} \implies L^2-Lr-r^2=0 \\
\therefore \color{red}{L = r\dfrac{1+\sqrt5}{2}=r \varphi}  \\
\triangle CSN: cos \angle NSC=\cos \alpha = \dfrac{r}{L} = \dfrac{r}{r\varphi} = \dfrac{1}{\varphi}\\
\triangle CSD: cos \alpha = \dfrac{4\varphi}{r}\implies \dfrac{1}{\varphi}= \dfrac{4\varphi}{r} \therefore \color{red}{r = 4\varphi^2}\\
Sabendo : \varphi^2=\varphi+1 \implies \varphi = \varphi^2-1\\
NO = NS - SO=r\varphi - 8\varphi = 4\varphi^3-8\varphi = 4\varphi^2.\varphi-8\varphi=4(\varphi+1)\varphi-8\varphi=\\
4\varphi^2-4\varphi =4(\varphi+1)-4\varphi =\boxed{4u}$

(Solution:by electron)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Let $r$ be the circle radius, $\phi = \frac{1+\sqrt 5}2$, and refer to the Figure above for additional labels (note in particular $CD\perp NS$). Recall also that $\phi^2 -\phi-1 = 0$.

1. Similarity $\triangle ABC \sim \triangle CNT$ yields $$\overline{NC} = r\sqrt \phi$$ and $$\overline{BC} = r\sqrt{\phi+1}=r\phi.$$
2. Similarity $\triangle CNS \sim \triangle CDS$ yields $$\overline{DS} = \frac{r}{\phi}.$$
3. We have $$\overline{OS} = \frac{2r}{\phi} = 8 \phi,$$hence $$r = 4\phi^2=4(\phi+1).$$
4. Finally \begin{eqnarray}\overline{NO} &=& \overline{BC}-\overline{OS}=\\&=& 4\phi(\phi+1)-8\phi =\\ &=& 4\phi^2-4\phi = 4.\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Can explain NC e DS?

Comment: Is saying that the golden section of the $SO$ segment is worth $8u$ the same as saying that the segment is worth $8\phi$?
So the test answer provided would be wrong because it gave $4u$ half of $8u$???

Comment: Nice answer. (+1)

Comment: @petaarantes the answer provided is correct, and corresponds to what I found. As soon as I have some more time I'll give you details on the other question of yours.

Comment: I would be grateful

Comment: @Intelligentipauca I didn't question the answer, I just wanted to understand what data were used in the triangle similarities

Comment: @petaarantes Ok, sorry for the delay. Let, e.g. $\overline{NC} = x$. Then the mentioned similarity yields $x:r =r: \sqrt{x^2-r^2}$. Can you proceeed from here?

Comment: @petaarantes as for the other similarity, letting $\overline{DS} = x$ we get $r\phi : r = r:x$, hence...

Comment: @dfnu Sorry I didn't understand. For me $\triangle CNT \sim \triangle ABC$ would be $\frac{AB}{r}=\frac{r}{\sqrt{x^2-r^2}}=\frac{BC}{x}$ . How does the value of $\phi$ arise in $ NC$ and $BC$?

Comment: Thank you for your attention and the solution. A colleague provided a detailed solution that I posted where I resolved my doubts.

Comment: @petaarantes $$AB:CT=BC:CN$$ $$x:r=\sqrt{r^2+x^2}:x$$ $$x^2=r\sqrt{r^2+x^2}$$ $$x^4=r^2(r^2+x^2)$$ $$x^4-r^2x^2-r^4=0$$ $$x^2=\phi r^2$$

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Thanks